# How to include a file OR PHP code with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

How can I include code, for example  using Javascript? Or if that can't be done, how can I include a whole PHP file?

P.S. Found some script called "require" or "include," but I prefer two lines of code instead of a huge library (using jQuery though). If that can't be done, let me know, I will try to think of something else.

EDIT:

Okay, an example of what I want to do:

```
function foo() { if(x = 1) return 1; else return 0; }
```

Then if the function returns 1, I want to either add HTML/PHP code to DIV tags OR I want to include a PHP file containing that code.

EDIT #2:

What about only HTML?

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<a href="google.com">a cool link</a>';
```

That doesn't seem to work either.

I have an empty div tag with id="test" in my code.

Comment: Please add more context to this. What do you want to include exactly? What is your use case?

Comment: I don't have a clue what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function foo() { 
  if(x = 1) {$("#divid").load("somephp.php");return 1;} 
  else return 0; 
}
```

Or

```
if (foo()) $("#divid").load("somephp.php");
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Okay, what about only HTML? document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<a href="google.com">a cool link</a>'; - doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Of course it works - you need jQuery loaded and the file has to be local to your server! Your last example also should work

Comment: Solved it. Had to move jQuery include above the script. No idea why this matters, never had this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can call any file as long as it is on your server.
It can't call files on the user's local files, for obvious security reasons.
However, javascript cannot, and will never be able to call PHP code, as in it cannot execute php code. This is because since javascript is client side, users can call their own javascript on your page, and execute PHP code, and potentially mess up your site or browse your backend.
You can, however add HTML code to your page using javascript, fairly simply using the innerHTML property of DOM elements or JQuery.
Javascript can also call more javascript code if you wanted, using eval()
If you wanted to call files off your server onto the page using javascript, you'd have to use **AJAX**
Google it up, and you can code it from scratch, or use JQuery's convenient AJAX handler.
Let's say you had a php file myfile.php that had some html/php, and you wanted to insert it into a div with the id "mydiv", or in css, "#mydiv"
If you just want to quickly load the html/php and push it into the div:

```
$("#mydiv").load("myfile.php");
```

If you want to have maximum control of the response from the html/php file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myfile.php", // url to load
    success : function(data) { // on success function
        // data is the response of the ajax request, the response text
        // you can manipulate it here
        manipulateData(data);
        $('#mydiv').html(data); // set the html of the div
    }
});
```

Comment: The files are on the server, I'm not looking to create a malicious site. But anyway, in that case, how can I include a PHP file with Javascript? I've updated the main post with more info.

Answer (score 0):

The only files could Javascript includes is Javascript files, what ever the extension is. and the only way to do it is using

```
<script src="path/to some/file.ext"></script>
```

You should note that the file should be javascript text contents, else errors may be generated.